# Who should get a developer certificate from Apple if client want their company name to show up in App Store

Tags: development-process, deployment, apple, appstore, product-owner

I am about start my first project with client, However I will work as a consultant. So do I need to get developer certificate and post my client's app in app store? Or I should ask my client to get the license and then I help them deploying the app on their name?

They don't want company name to be my organisation but they want their company name to show up in App Store.

However the developer of app is my organisation not them.

How to deal with this situation?

Comment: Two enrollments.  A developer should enroll to prove they know what they're doing (test apps on their own iOS devices).  A client should enroll to control their apps under their own company name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has this scenario covered. Your client will need to join the iOS dev program so they can post things to the store. They can then add you to their program for development certificates and such if you don't have your own as well as provision an iTunes connect account for you to publish to the store on their behalf.

I would advise getting your own iOS dev program account if for no other reason than convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate out the different parts of the process.

- What hardware, software, licenses, registration do you need to develop and test the code? You have to decide if you are going to use resources they have that the client owns; or if they are going to purchase and keep these tools; Or if they expect you to provide them.
- Once the software is ready to be released via the app store you have to look at the ultimate consumer of the software. Will they want to see that the software was made by doNotCheckMyBlog LLC, or by your client. Most of the time the client should be the one listed. They are marketing the app in support of the rest of their business. You may be the one submitting all the documentation and code to get accepted by the app store, but their name should be on the documents
- Keep in mind that you have a contract. Once the software is released the responsibilities for bug fixes, upgrades, and new versions could be handled either in-house or by another development company.